# Eclipse Flash Builder 4: Syntax customization?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting, flash-builder

Using Flash Builder 4 (FB), is there a way to customize syntax highlighting for variable scope (member, parameter, local)?

I've heard this is possible in other Eclipse plugins and wondering if it is possible with FB or if not is there an easy way to add it manually?

Cheers,
Jono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
Even in version 4.5, syntax highlighting is still the same primitive, useless crap.